Telegram bot cannot use file_id for sending the file that he got one day ago
While creating a telegram bot, I encountered the problem that the bot cannot use file_id of the file which I sent to the bot about 1 day ago.
I am using aiogram and I have the similar lines in the code:
# PROCESSING CALLBACK BEFORE
file_id = MOCK_DB['image_1']
await bot.send_photo(callback_query.from_user.id, file_id, caption="the image", reply_markup=keyboard.as_markup())
# PROCESSING CALLBACK AFTER

In the MOCK_DB there is the file_id which I got from @RawDataBot on my photo. Then I forwarded this photo to my bot. Initially, everythink was ok, and the bot sent the image without any problems. But next day it didn't send nothing. The logs say:
27-11-2024 12:12:54 - ERROR - Cause exception while process update id=... by bot id=...
TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 309, in _process_update
    response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 158, in feed_update
    response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/middlewares/error.py", line 25, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/middlewares/user_context.py", line 27, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/fsm/middleware.py", line 41, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 276, in _listen_update
    return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 116, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 111, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 136, in _propagate_event
    response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
  File "/root/loyalty/loyalty.py", line 215, in process_callback
    await bot.send_photo(callback_query.from_user.id, file_id, caption="the image", reply_markup=keyboard.as_markup())
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 2773, in send_photo
    return await self(call, request_timeout=request_timeout)
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 432, in __call__
    return await self.session(self, method, timeout=request_timeout)
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/base.py", line 257, in __call__
    return cast(TelegramType, await middleware(bot, method))
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.py", line 179, in make_request
    response = self.check_response(
  File "/root/bazar_shop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/base.py", line 120, in check_response
    raise TelegramBadRequest(method=method, message=description)
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified

On the faq of the telegram it is said that the file_id can be considered as permanent, however the bot cannot use it after one day. When I forward the image to the bot second time (the image has the same file_id), the bot again is able to send the photo. Where is my problem?
I am expecting to use the file_id in the bot. The bot shouldn't forget the file_id.
PS:
The telegram bot api returns on my try to send the image, which was known by the bot one day ago:
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified'}

I have no idea how to use file_id in any time
